# Smarty not loading block content in sub include

Tags: html, smarty, smarty3

Working with the Smarty template engine and I am trying to reduce reused code across multiple layout pages I use. The below works as expected... doctype gets included, meta tags get included, header_scripts takes in the scripts in the page that extends layout etc.... but `{include file=$layout.box_title}` has both html and another block in it. It catches the html and parses it but wont add the block content. It will pick up default code in the block but not the given from the used page. It works ok if I copy the included file code and place it where the include line is.

I am wondering if this is a bug, a load order issue or it what I am trying is even possible.

```
layout.tpl
====================================================
{include file=$tpls.doctype}
<head>
    {include file=$tpls.meta}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$assets_url}build/css/base.min.css">
    {block name=header_scripts}{/block}
    {include file=$tpls.flaty_showhouse_css}
</head>
<body>
    {include file=$tpls.navbar}

    <div class="container" id="main-container">
        {include file=$tpls.sidebar}

        <div id="main-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="box">

                        {include file=$layout.box_title}

                        <div class="box-content clearfix showhouse-border">



block_title.tpl
===================================
<div class="box-title showhouse-colour-dark">
    <h3>{block name=box_title}{/block}</h3>
    <div class="box-tool">
        <a class="entity_button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is block_title.tpl supposed to be box_title.tpl?

Comment: the block with the name box_title doesn't appear in the parent templates, nor does it have any content defined inside of it (it's an empty block). From the documentation: The {block} template source area of a child template will replace the correponding areas in the parent template(s).  http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.block.tpl